# Query in spring data mongo repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to write custom query on spring data mongodb. Something like this:

```
public interface CarRepo extends MongoRepository<Car, String> {


  @Query("select distinct(brand) from Car ")
  public List<String> findDistinctBrand();
}
```

But it's throwing an error "`Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:` ". How can I achieve that?

Comment: You are giving sql query in `@Query`part. this is completely wrong. And for distinct support of `mongodb`check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203724/distinct-in-spring-data-mongodb) question's answers for spirng data part

Comment: But in criteria what should I write for the given query(select distinct(brand) from Car)?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not support distinct command. 
It only supports returning distinct field values using the [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) command.

You need to use Mongodb template, for your results:

```
DBCollection colllection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.where("your column").is("your value");
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
List list = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName")
    .distinct("source",query.getQueryObject());
```

Comment: **this.mongoTemplate.getCollection("Car").distinct("brand")** This piece of code work for me . Thanks.

Comment: @yogi If the field source is dbref, in that case, it's not working. how can I get the dbref field also?

Comment: MongoTemplate is not required to query for distinct attributes, see:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score -1):

You are using `SQL` to query in mongodb, but mongodb has its own query language. You need to write query in that language. As you are going to use `distinct` command you cannot user `Query` annotation or spring data query to do that. You need to create custom repository and execute distinct command using `MongoTemplate`.

Comment: Untrue, see:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score -1):

Per [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) you should be able to accomplish this by simply defining the method in your repository interface, without the help of `@Query`:

```
public interface CarRepo extends MongoRepository<Car, String> {
    public List<String> findDistinctBrand();
}
```

Comment: It is Throw Exception `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findDistinctPublisher found for type News!`

Comment: @fuat then you've done something else wrong. The docs clearly state this is doable, and  have done so myself.

Comment: I did this in repository interface `Set<String> findDistinctPublisher();`  `Publisher` is a property of the object. So is there anything wrong ?