# Spring Data mongo - issue with Distinct collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Spring Data Mongo distinct doesn't works. I've following two documents.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca746fd92bc0733a4a6633b"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Kerr",
    "emailId" : "john.kerr@gmail.com",
    "hobbies" : [ 
        {
            "interest" : "Indoor",
            "sports" : "Chess"
        }, 
        {
            "interest" : "Loveoor",
            "sports" : "Table Tennis"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.example.Person"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca746fd92bc0733a4a6633c"),
    "firstName" : "Neha",
    "lastName" : "Parate",
    "emailId" : "john.kerr@gmail.com",
    "hobbies" : [ 
        {
            "interest" : "Indoor",
            "sports" : "Chess"
        }, 
        {
            "interest" : "Loveoor",
            "sports" : "Table Tennis"
        }, 
        {
            "interest" : "Happydoor",
            "sports" : "Lawn Tennis"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.example.Person"
}
```

When I do `db.person.distinct('hobbies')`, I get the distinct records easily.

```
[
    {
        "interest" : "Indoor",
        "sports" : "Chess"
    },
    {
        "interest" : "Loveoor",
        "sports" : "Table Tennis"
    },
    {
        "interest" : "Happydoor",
        "sports" : "Lawn Tennis"
    }
]
```

The same I wants to do using Spring Data Mongo or MongoTemplate. But none of the ways things are working.

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'hobbies' : 1}")
List<Person> findByDistinctHobbies();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of *Spring Data Mongo* as per docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.query.distinct. You can even query to the embedded document to find out the `distinct` documents.

Through MongoTemplate you can achieve like below:

```
List<Object> object = mongoTemplate.query(Person.class).distinct("hobbies").all();
     for (Object object2 : object) {
       Hobbies hobbies = (Hobbies) object2;
       System.out.println(hobbies);
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608104/spring-data-mongo-perform-distinct-but-doesnt-pull-embedded-documents-in-res ?